Parsing character to str_getcsv for specific use case not splitting
I'm working inside a Laravel 11 application running PHP 8.3. I need to get the CSV contents and map the data. The character least likely to be used in a CSV is: ± and I need to use this as my delimiter. When I pass it and var_dump the outputs it doesn't actually split anything. What am I missing?
$chunk = ['Foo±Bar±Test±±Another item'];

$data = array_map(function ($row) {
    return str_getcsv($row, mb_strtolower('±'));
}, $chunk);

                            
var_dump($data);

See reproduction

separator: Set the field delimiter (one single-byte character only). And ± is 2 bytes so it won't work.

Now the question is, what  does the "least likely to be used in a CSV character" mean and how it justifies using it as a deliiter?

provided this is some custom format unrelated to CSV, why not to simply use explode()?

@Ryan You won't have this XY Problem if your input data is properly generated, valid, csv-formatted text with double quote wrapping and escaping.  Fix your input data so that you don't need some hacky, unreliable workaround to parse the data.  In your current design, your script will corrupt data if there is a non-delimiting ± in any of the values in the payload.

You can work around using different approach to parse your CSV data.
One option is to use the explode function to split the string manually.
 return explode('±', $row);
}, $chunk);

var_dump($data);

